# Docker build hadoop system: how to keep container running

Tags: docker, hadoop

Below is one of my container in hadoop system. I want to keep the container running after I use "docker-compose up -d". I have used the command "/usr/bin/yes" to keep the container running. However, it wastes resources. Is there any answer? Thank you.

```
version: "3.0"
services:
    Active_NN:
        container_name: active_nn
        image: active_nn
        user: root
        privileged: true
        networks:
            - Hadoop_Cluster
        hostname: active-nn
        ports:
            - 9870:9870
            - 8020:8020
        command: bash -c "service ssh restart && /usr/bin/yes"
```

Comment: What's the actual process the container should be running (it looks like a Hadoop name node)?  Run that single process as a foreground process.

Comment: Why can't you have something like `tail -f /var/log/hadoop/namenode.log`? Which is basically the same that running `hadoop namenode` in the foreground would do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use command "sleep 9999999999" to hold container

Comment: And what happens after the `9999999999`-th second?

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is a simple temporary solution for about 300 years. Certainly, we can use kubernetes's `pause` to do this.

Comment: I'm just suggesting tailing the log or running daemons in the forehead so `docker logs` works properly is far more useful. OP didn't mention k8s